# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio how to get errors/console message to output VS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

VS output doesn't work with node.js. I'd it to work like webStorm for example
Help, how to set VS?

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/FAQ

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki

I'm sure you will find if the feature you'll looking for is available...